Apache eCharts - yAxis legend without overlap
With eCharts, I'm trying to find a solution to display the yAxis name properly for every screen size and chart content.
Starting from this example, where the axis name overlaps with the axis labels:


option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: [{
    name: "TEST",
    nameLocation: "middle",
  }],
  series: [
    {
      data: [1500, 2300, 2240, 2180, 1350, 1470, 2600],
      type: 'line',
    }
  ]
};



I tried adding a padding to move the name and make it not overlap.


  yAxis: [
    {
      name: 'TEST',
      nameLocation: 'middle',
      nameTextStyle: {
        padding: [0, 0, 50, 0]
      }
    }
  ],



but that has two problems:

it doesn't always work if the labels are longer (e.g. if the data has 8 digits instead of 4)
if I reduce slightly the screen size, the name of the axis goes out of bounds.

How can I solve this problem? Is there a way to express the margin in a relative way from the axis labels?

You can specify an absolute distance in pixel for grid: Example

thank you :)
ok, that would prevent the axis name to go out of bounds, but if the labels are longer, it would overlap. There's any way to prevent that?

I dont think there is. You could only change the nameLocation to 'end'.
